# Create a non partition container in Azure cosmos db using python script

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using this script to create a non partition container, i.e. without specifying any partition key while running the python script. I want to insert some records to this container without specifying the partition key. Since this is not achievable on azure portal, I am doing it using python script.

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient, PartitionKey
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

endpoint = "https://test-ck.documents.azure.com:443/"
account_key = ACCOUNT_KEY

client = CosmosClient(url=endpoint, credential=account_key)
database_name = "test"
container_name = "testcontainer"

try:
    print("Connection made")
    client.create_database_if_not_exists(database_name)
    databases = client.get_database_client(database_name)

    container = databases.create_container_if_not_exists(container_name, partition_key=None)
    print(f"Container '{container_name}' created without a partition key")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Add 50 sample records
sample_records = [
    {"id": str(i), "name": f"Person{i}", "age": 25 + i} for i in range(1, 51)
]

for record in sample_records:
    try:
        container.upsert_item(record)
        print(f"Inserted item with id: {record['id']}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error inserting item: {e}")
```

is creating a container without specifying any partition key doable?

Comment: Are you facing any error while executing the above code?

Comment: Yes, the error is 
```
An error occurred: (BadRequest) Message: {"Errors":["A Partition key definition is not specified in the request."]}
ActivityId: d554446e-e98f-447c-8418-28c1a82aee03, Request URI: /apps/09ebd2ab-04b1-4707-86b7-791cc1126a10/services/eb850ba7-64bc-4c7f-8c00-a24fbfe031cb/partitions/768d1f99-d2a8-4227-b792-06f341a6c717/replicas/133533279025895247p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0
```

Comment: In this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/migrate-containers-partitioned-to-nonpartitioned?tabs=dotnetv3) it is mentioned that container without a partition key can be created only by using `.NET`, `Java`, `NodeJs`.

Comment: Please *edit your question* when sharing things like errors, which are formatted-text and are very difficult to read as a comment. Aside from that: non partitioned containers are considered *legacy* - it's not something you should be doing.

Comment: Hi David, I know the non partitioned containers are legacy. But I have to implement a PoC in which I have to partition a non partition container to a partition container, Since Azure has disabled all the ways to create a non partitioned container, can you suggest a way to create a non partition container to implement this PoC?